# realtime plotting in matlab using SURF

Tags: matlab, real-time

i want to plot a 3d graph using [surf](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/surf.html) in matlab. i know how to plot it just using surf:

```
k = 5;
n = 2^k-1;
[x,y,z] = sphere(n);
c = hadamard(2^k);
p=surf(x,y,z);
```

but i want to plot this in realtime, and i want to update the values using set.
I tired:`set(p,"XData",Xvalue,"YData",Yvalue,"ZData",Zvalue);` but its giving me errors. has anyone plotted using surf in realtime?

Comment: Use single quotes for property names: `set(p,'XData',Xvalue,'YData',Yvalue,'ZData',Zvalue);`, followed by `drawnow` to flush the graphics queue.

Comment: thank you, i mistyped the ", yep i will add the drawnow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) you can use the linkdata command or toolbar button (or even Tools -> Link from the plot window)

2) programmatically: you need to call the command 'refreshdata' to signal that new data is available:

```
%% Define the data
t=linspace(0,2*pi,40);
y=sin(t);

%% Create the plot and set teh datasources
h=plot(t,y)
set(h,'YDataSource','y')
set(h,'XDataSource','t')

%% Now update the data and the plot
pause
y=sin(2*t);
refreshdata
```

This shows it for the `plot`, but expect `surf` will behave the same.